# Is there a way to determine if the media-iframe is visible?

Tags: media-library

My plugin adds a tab to the media iframe and I need to know when it is running within the iframe. Using jQuery('#media-iframe').is(':visible’) does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a way to do it:

1. Add an element to the contents of the frame such as a text input
   with and ID (i.e. 'search_text')
2. In the plugin's CSS file, style the
   element to be visible only when it is displayed in the frame:

   ```
   #search_text {
      display: none;
   }

   #media-upload #search_text {
      display: inline;
   }
   ```
3. Test if the element is visible:

   if(jQuery("#search_text").is(":visible")) {
   }